# getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND when using tedious in node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to connect to a local SQL Express server using [Tedious](https://github.com/pekim/tedious) but keep getting

```
failed Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
```

Am I using the wrong address here?

```
  var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;

  var config = {
    userName: 'sa',
    password: 'mypassword',
    server: 'LOCALHOST\\SQLEXPRESS',
  };

  var connection = new Connection(config);

  connection.on('connect', function(err) {
    // If no error, then good to go...
      if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      } 
      executeStatement();
    }
  );
```

Comment: Try using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` for `server`.

Comment: yes, by using `localhost` I get `connect ECONNREFUSED` error instead. how do I chose the sqlexpress server instance after that?

Comment: @Cotten is your issue resolved? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @CrazyNooB yes, sorry, see answer below

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> "Microsoft style strings of hostname\instancename are not supported."
>    - [pekim](https://github.com/pekim)

I posted the same issue on github and here is the full answer: https://github.com/pekim/tedious/issues/118

Answer (score 0):

Just as @Cotten said, but here is an example.

TCP/IP connection must be enabled and the port shouldn't be included within the server string, it must go inside the configuration as a numeric value.

```
var config = {  
    server: 'your_ip_address',
    authentication: {
        type: 'default',
        options: {
            userName: 'your_username',
            password: 'your_password'
        }
    },
    options: {
        database: 'your_database',
        port: 1234  //your port number
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can choose between using port and instance name when connecting. I find using instance name more convenient (easy to obtain information). In options part of config just comment out port (if you have it) and add "instanceName" key with instace name value like this:

```
var config = {  
    server: 'localhost',
    authentication: {
        type: 'default',
        options: {
            userName: 'sa', 
            password: 'password' 
        }
    },
    options: {
        encrypt: false,
        database: 'test',
        //port: 4966,
        instanceName: "INSTANCA1"
    }
};
```

Same is said on previously mentioned https://github.com/pekim/tedious/issues/118, but I have overlooked it at first and lost half an hour on looking for solution.